# How to create a numeric sequence in the columns initial record and final record?

Tags: mysql

How to create a numeric sequence in the columns initial record and final record, note: the records must be the same in both columns!
Note: I want to repeat the information from the other columns, generating the sequence only in initial record and final record, both columns as the same sequence number

```
INSERT INTO table ('company', 'name', 'phone', 'initial_register', 'final_register', 'sales_id', 'justification', 'data_inserted', 'protocol')
     VALUES (1, 'Joao', '99999-0000', '', '', 'Sale at the credential', '2020-11-04 15:43:09', NULL);
     WHERE initial_register> 000001
     AND final_register <100000
```

Comment: For a same entry, it should have the same value in both columns?

Comment: write a stored procedure with a loop or do the loop in another language

Comment: INSERT does not have WHERE clause

Comment: @Dharman I think that's some kind of pseudo code

Comment: @Cid that's right, in the set sequence

Comment: @Dharman how can I insert this string?
do you have any idea?

Comment: What do you mean? What string? Your SQL is not valid, it looks more like a pseudo code. Can you please explain the question better? Please use [edit] button to add more details.

Comment: @Dharman Take a look now at the description

Comment: something like... `AUTO_INCREMENT` ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this another way, but it is still bringing the value to zero in the column initial record and final record and I want sequential.

```
> Insert Into table (    
>       company,
>       name,
>       phone,
>       initial_register,  
>       final_register 
> ) 
>SELECT
>      '5' as company,
>      name,
>      phone,  
>      initial_register >=1 and initial_register <= 3 as 
>initial_register,  
>      final_register >=1 and final_register <= 3 as final_register,    
>from table Where company  = 1
```